# Can this identify-this question be reopened?

Tags: support, status-completed, specific-question, closed-questions

[This question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/11031/i-have-pictures-of-some-scenes-from-this-movie) is a picture-only identify-this type of question.  That class of question was [recently discussed](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/924/209), and my answer there has +8/-0 votes, which indicates this type of question is allowed.  The question was closed by a mod as Not A Real Question (I acknowledge it may have been flagged, but since those flags aren't necessarily public, I can't speak to it):

> It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form. For help clarifying this question so that it can be reopened, see the FAQ.

This maybe applies to the original revision of the question, which had links to the images instead of having them inline (it looks like the SE image uploader couldn't process the Dropbox links that were there originally).  That's since been remedied.

The images in the question seem to be ones taken by the question asker.  A Google Image search using one of them returns 0 results, so that tool isn't helpful, in spite of the snarky comment on the question.

Can this question be reopened?

Comment: I still hate that question but if you guys are ok with it then i can ignore it..

Comment: I think as how we interact with Stack sites evolves (mobile app mobile app mobile app), quick snaps similar to the ones in that question will become much more common.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While i'm not a fan of picture-only id questions (I'm the one that started the meta), I'm not going to go against the major site concensus.  I've reopened the question.

Answer (score 1):

Devil's advocate here, but: does the fact that people didn't downvote your *answer* mean that the community agrees that the *question* is acceptable? I know if I disapproved of a question I would act on the question itself, not an answer.

Also:
Where are the OPs getting these pictures? Are these just random images they find on the internet somewhere that they want identified? Those images look an awful lot like photographs (I think I see a price sticker in the top-left corner of the first image).

Comment: Yes, we should assume that upvotes to my Meta answer [indicate agreement](http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/faq#vote-differences), barring comments that clarify the purpose of the upvotes.

Comment: In this case, yes I think the user took the photos themselves.  The photos don't have any other Google Image Search results, so they don't seem to be elsewhere on the internet.

Comment: @Keen I thought you were referring to the answer on the actual question-- which had 8 upvotes-- though I acknowledge it makes no sense bc that is not your answer. The link to the meta question was not directing me there, but to the question on main.

Comment: Oh, well then.  I took 'your' to mean 'my' not some 'royal your'.